# Troubleshooting matplotlib - no plots appear despite using plot.show() (Linux WSL)

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use (python) matplotlib to generate simple plots, but when I run any python program doing so, no plot appears. I am using `plt.show()`. The programs run without errors or warnings, but no plot appears. I have included a simple example below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3]
y = [0,1,2]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I have installed matplotlib using pip3 (`pip3 install matplotlib`) to my python virtual environment. As I stated above, when I run this program (either in my WSL Ubuntu terminal, or in the VSCode terminal) in my virtual environment using `python3 simple-plot.py`, the program finishes quickly and outputs no errors or warnings, but simply does not produce a plot.

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this; I went through the matplotlib troubleshooting page but I did not get anything out of it. Any suggestions are appreciated.

System details:

```
$uname -a
Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 GNU/Linux
$python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
$pip3 --version
pip 20.0.2
$python3
>>>import matplotlib as mpl
>>>mpl.__version__
'3.7.1'
>>>exit()
$python3 simple-plot.py
$ # No errors or warnings
```

Comment: Is Visual Studio code also running in WSL? From what I've seen about WSL, it is purely command line based, so you would not be able to have matplotlib show figures.

Comment: Yes, VSCode is also running in WSL. Maybe that explains it. If so, then what are my options? I'd rather not use Jupyter Notebooks or Anaconda...is there another option?

Comment: What are your requirements? How about miniconda?

Comment: My requirements are minimal, I feel like I must be missing the obvious solution. I simply want to be able to make a virtual environment, install matplotlib, numpy and a few other standard libraries, and make basic plots.

Comment: miniconda is a lightweight version of anaconda. You can install it on a windows computer and do what you are looking to do.

Comment: You said VSCode is running in WSL2, does this means that your WSL2 has a desktop GUI? Or are you using VSCode on windows, and connect to development environments in WSL2?